# How to list my billing plans?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-rest-sdk

How can I list the number of billing plans that I have created? I have lost track of them. 
I know how to create a billing plan following this guide for PHP http://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/doc/billing/CreatePlan.html 
 But apparently there is no way of listing them (unless I store them in my own database before using the sdk to create them?).